# Need help can figure out this project in VB

Tags: vb.net

This is what i have so far. cant seem to get it to work these are the guidelines

***Specifics
You will use 1 file to enter all the scores. The file is named Data.txt and should be stored in the projects Debug folder. The scores are floating point numbers.

One button should calculate the mean, range, and standard deviation and display them. 
You must use separate functions to calculate the 3 statistics.

One button should display the frequencies in tabular form. For this exercise, the frequencies we are interested in are as follows:

```
# scores < 60
60 <= # scores < 70
70 <= # scores < 80
80 <= # scores < 90
90 <= # scores
```

You must use a separate array to hold the totals for the individual ranges.

All scores should be displayed in a listbox.***

```
Option Strict On
Public Class Form1

    Private names() As String = IO.File.ReadAllLines("data.txt")
    Private scores(names.Count - 1) As double

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        For i As Integer = 0 To names.Count - 1
            scores(i) = CInt(names(i))
        Next
    End Sub
    Private Sub Button3_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
        Me.Close()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim sum As Double = 0
        mean(sum)
        OutputListBox.Items.Add(sum)
    End Sub

    Function mean(ByRef sum As Double) As Double
        Dim total As Double = scores(0)

        For i As Double = 0 To scores.Count - 1
            sum = 
        Next
        Return sum
    End Function

End Class
```

Comment: What problems are you having?

Comment: i just cant figure it out at all. cant get the mean, range, or standard deviation from the txt file. and the text file can contain any types of "test" grade numbers.

Comment: Well, it's going to be difficult to help. The code you've posted for the `mean()` function doesn't do anything (or compile, with the incomplete expression `sum =`). You must at least describe the specific problems you're having in order for us to help you.

Comment: I know thats the whole thing. i dont understand any of it. I cant get the functions to work. I need the buttonclick to ppass the data.txt file to the three different functions to calculate the mean, range, and standard deviation.

Answer (score 0):

I won't do all of the work for you, but here is a restructuring of your form with the mean implemented and some comments so you can figure out what is happening:

```
Option Strict On
Option Explicit On

Partial Public Class Form1

    Private scores() As Double

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Try
            ' Clear the list view
            ListView1.Clear()

            ' First, load the scores from the file into memory
            Call LoadScores()

            Dim value As Double

            ' Next, calculate the mean
            value = CalculateMean()
            ' And add it to the list view
            ListView1.Items.Add("Mean = " & value.ToString)

            ' Now calculate the other items and display them


        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub

    ''' <summary>
    ''' This method loads the scores from the file into the scores array
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <remarks></remarks>
    Private Sub LoadScores()

        Dim stringScores() As String

        ' Read all of the scores in the file into an array of strings
        stringScores = IO.File.ReadAllLines("data.txt")

        ' Resize the scores array to hold all of the values in the file
        ReDim scores(stringScores.Length)

        Dim counter As Integer

        ' Now convert those strings to numbers, and store them in scores
        For Each sValue As String In stringScores
            ' Convert the string value from the file into a double and store it in the current location in the scores array
            scores(counter) = CDbl(sValue)
            ' Keep track of our position in the scores array
            counter += 1
        Next
    End Sub

    ''' <summary>
    ''' The mean is the sum of the scores divided by the total number of scores
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <returns></returns>
    ''' <remarks></remarks>
    Function CalculateMean() As Double

        If scores.Length <> 0 Then
            Dim total As Double

            For Each value As Double In scores
                total += value
            Next

            Return total / scores.Length
        Else
            ' Avoid a divide by zero error
            Return 0
        End If
    End Function

    Private Sub Button3_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
        Me.Close()
    End Sub


End Class
```

Comment: thanks alot! can you just tell me the equation to range, and standard deviation?!

Comment: have you done any research on how to calculate the standard deviation? I found a couple of suggestions with a quick google search. How about if you take a crack at implementing it, then we can see what needs to be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

As with any problem, start by breaking it down and do one piece at a time.  A common approach is to make one function implement one (or one part of a) requirement, so start there.

1. Read the file to get the scores.  For this exercise, you have a hard-coded name, but it is just as easy to make the file reading function take the name as a parameter.  You know the scores are listed as floating-point numbers, so you will return them as `Double` or `Single`.  I see that you used an array in the code you have so far, so we'll stick with that.  With that information, we can make the signature of the function

   ```
   Public Function ReadScoresFromFile(fileName As String) As Double()
   ```
2. Calculate the mean, range, and standard deviation; three things, three functions.  Based on the mathematical definitions of these three things, you will need functions that take in a sequence of numbers and will return one number.  This should lead you to the function definitions:

   ```
   Public Function Mean(values As Double()) As Double
   Public Function Range(values As Double()) As Double
   Public Function StandardDeviation(values As Double()) As Double
   ```

   A quick search online or through your math/statistics book should give you definitions and formulas that you can turn into code.  *Hint:* You may be able to call one function from one of the others to simplify the work.
3. Group scores into ranges.  As with the file name, you have a specified list of ranges.  You could try to parametrize the function to take the ranges as an argument, but its probably not worth the effort for this exercise.  So, we know have a sequence of scores and need a list of total of number of scores in each range.  Since totals will be integral numbers and not floating-point, we'll pick the type accordingly.

   ```
   Public Function CountInRanges(scores as Double()) As Integer()
   ```

At this point, you have all the functions you need to get the data you need.  Now you just have to make the various button click handlers call the appropriate functions and put the results in the appropriate labels, list boxes, etc.  Use the arguments and return types to help you figure out the flow of data from one function to the next, using variables as needed to hold intermediate results.

A few things I noticed from the code you showed (none of these are required to solve your immediate problem, but could be helpful now and in the future.):

- Try to give your controls meaningful names.  `AggregatesButton`, `RangesButton`, `MeanLabel`, etc are much easier to remember than `Button1`, `Button2`, etc.  (There are various styles for names as well.  Some people will use a prefix instead of a suffix for names like `btnAggregates`, `btnRanges`, `lblMean`.)
- The numeric types all have a Shared `Parse` method.  You may consider using this instead of the conversion as it allows you to specify several options about how to parse the number from a string.  For now, the conversion will probably suffice, but this is at least something to tuck away for later.
- I don't know what topics your class will cover later, but you may consider looking into the [For Each](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ebk1751.aspx) loop instead of the standard For loop.  This can be useful when you need to do something 'for each' item in a sequence but don't care about the index, such as the Mean, Range, StandardDeviation, and CountInRanges calculations.  This can make your code cleaner because you won't keep referencing the array and makes it easier to convert to other sequence classes that you may run into later (eg: List, Collection, etc).  It also keeps you from accidentally modifying the array, which you never want to do in any of those functions.